# Django: query on properties of set of foreign keyed objects

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to use the Django query tools to return a list of objects that meet some criteria which may have to do with a set of related objects. Here's what I mean:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Chapter(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    length = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In this query, I want to retrieve all `Books` where every component `Chapter` has `length > 100`.

I realize I could do something like:

```
for book in Book.objects.all():
    for chapter in book.chapter_set.all():
        {do whatever to record if this chapter is valid/invalid}
```

However this is obviously the most naive way to approach it. I'm sure there's a nice way to avoid the nested `for` loop, but I'd like to avoid iterating over every object in the first place.

Is there a way I can use the various Django tools to construct queries which make use of the properties of objects in the `chapter_set`? I can't find anything in the docs that works in this way- every example uses the `_set` of one particular instance rather than incorporating it a query.

For example, I think the following SQL would directly accomplish what I'm trying to do here (this is untested until I get back to my computer later on, perhaps the subselect alone would work):

```
select * from book b, (select book_id 
                       from chapter
                       group by book_id
                       having min(length) = 100 ) x
where b.book_id = x.book_id;
```

I'm also trying to avoid raw SQL, so even if this (or some version of it) works, I'd like to learn more about the Django query capabilities by finding out how this would translate to some combination of `filter()`, `F()`, `Q()`, etc expressions.

Comment: Sorry completely misread the question. Will post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try querying for all the `Book`s except those that have at least one `Chapter` with a `length` less than or equal to 100. For example:

```
books = Book.objects.exclude(chapter__length__le=100)
```

Comment: Great idea, this is something I just hadn't considered. If there's no way to directly address properties of groups of FKed objects in the query, I think using excludes will be the way I need to go. Thank you!